# How to stop TubeLight from flicking when the water heater is turned on

Tags: electrical, water-heater, light, voltage

Please find the video here. Whenever I turn on the water hater (tanked AO Smith HSE-VAS-X-015 Storage 15 Litre Vertical Water Heater (Geyser)), the tube light flickers. I'd like to stop that.

Should I be worried if the light flickers when something else starts to draw power? Is it a sign of some problem ?

[LED Tube light flickering](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13cwhme4wcc7M7ljYCw-6BNYspbNrqsdO/view?usp=sharing)

The same thing is happening whenever the mixer grinder is turned on.

Please check out how the 9W LED bulbs flicker when I turn on the driller:

[LED bulb 1 flickering](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z3sBPLSNQ83feg99rwmeejdkb_MQ5ASy/view?usp=sharing)

[LED bulb 2 flickering](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJ6WJQFP0BuH19J4TpiHgUde5uDA5iYF/view?usp=sharing)

**I have a 3-phase electric service.**

Comment: Is the light LED or florescent?

Comment: It's LED , 20W Tubelight batten from phillips

Comment: I do not know enough, but maybe the LED is on the same phase as the heater/grinder.  LEDs seem more sensitive to changes in power.  A large power use could cause the flickering, but there can be other problems.

Comment: May be the heavy weights like Heater , Mixer grinder , wet grinder , AC , washing machine , fridge, microwave oven should be on one phase and rest of the appliances and lighting fixtures on the other phase ? Could you explain more about other problems also please ? I will ask the electrician to look into it

Comment: Will need an expert to answer, either on here or even better an electrician there who can really see what you have.  Flickering might just be a LED going bad.

Comment: I don't know my electrician just says "it is what it is "

Comment: Add extra output capacitance to the LED driver's output. Mind the voltage, and use 2200uf per amp to cut it down orders of magnitude.  The constant current feedback loop won't mind being dampned as the current only changes due to temp, which takes a long time. With a current-limited driver (as most are), you can really jam a lot of caps on there w/o blowing a fuse or triggering short-circuit protection like with constant voltage supplies.

Comment: @dandavis - I couldn't understand , can you give me detailed steps so I can understand and try. Thanks. I've updated my question just thought to let you know

Comment: @crip659 - Please find my updated question

Comment: You need to use your multi-meter to measure the voltage going to the LED chain. Then order a capacitor of higher voltage than that, by about 25% extra. Eg. if you measure 28v, get a 35v cap. You can get amps by dividing the watts the light uses by the above voltage. Then multiply amps by ~2000 to get the number of microfarads of capacitance you need to fill in the missing power and prevent flickering. It's usually cheapest to by several caps at once, and if one is not enough you can add two, but I wouldn't go three, that's probably too much.

Comment: @dandavis - I've some experience of soldering with mobile phone mother boards to do some jumper like that

Comment: @dandavis - Seems like a great idea , But if there are any helpful articles that you can point to me , I'd appreciate. By the way these light flickering when some other appliance starts to drawing power.. is it a sign of some problem ?

Comment: What sort of water heater do you have? Tanked or tankless?

Comment: It's tanked Water heater **AO Smith HSE-VAS-X-015 Storage 15 Litre Vertical Water Heater (Geyser)**

Comment: `I don't know my electrician just says "it is what it is "` sounds like it's time to find a new electrician!

Comment: @FreeMan - Yes , but many of them are saying , it's normal. But I wonder when I turn on the high energy drawing appliance , if it flicks that means the current is going less atleast for a second , this can't be good for other appliances which run predominantly with motors right ... e.g AC,Fridge,Chimney,washing machine, Grinder etc..

Comment: A 15 liter tank? That's only about 3.5 US gallons. Is this a single point-of-use heater for a sink? This surely isn't feeding a tub/shower. Do you have more than one of these heaters for different sinks around the house?

Comment: @FreeMan - This heater is just for one Bathroom tap for rest of the taps and showers what directly comes from the over head water tank.I use just have one water heater.